# Property does not exist on type of initialized object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I assign data to an object of interface.

I have created my interfaces with optionnal fields

```
export interface IWeek {
    type?: number;
    required?: string;
}


export interface IItem {
    code?: string;
    recipe?: IRecipes;
}

export interface IMenu {
    week?: IWeek;
    items?: IItem[];
    title?: string;
}
```

Then I Assign data to object

```
const data :IMenu ={} ;
data.week.type=date;
data.title=title;
recipes.map(elm => {
  data.items.push({code:code,recipe:elm})
})
```

I get error that items does not existe on the typed object

```
ERROR in src/app/validation-dialog/validation-dialog.service.ts(13,10): error TS2339: Property 'week' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/validation-dialog/validation-dialog.service.ts(14,10): error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/validation-dialog/validation-dialog.service.ts(16,12): error TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Comment: I get the same error `Cannot set property 'type' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the property `items`. Initialize it to an empty array first.

```
const data: IMenu = {};
data.items = [];
```

Comment: I have tried but also `week` and `title` are not defined